# negative pixels in computer vision (kernels application)

Tags: python, opencv

When we apply kernels, with negative values (like sharping ones), in some cases we can get pixels with negative values. How does it work in this case if pixel values vary from
0 to 255?
I wonder if anyone helps...

Answer (score 0):

After applying your filter, clamp the values to the needed range.

Before C++20:

```
value = std::min(std::max(value, 0), 255);
```

After C++20:

```
value = std::clamp(value, 0, 255);
```

If your `value` is of type other than `int` (e.g. `int32_t`), you should specify the type:

```
value = std::clamp<int32_t>(value, 0, 255);
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong language! I usually do C++. Maybe, if you add code to your question, someone could give you advice. I'll leave my answer for now; if someone provides something more appropriate, I'll delete it.